# routing in web api use slash instead of questionmark

Tags: webapi, .net-8.0

I have controller called Player

I want to access each player like this:

```
GET /msdo/v1/player/5
```

however currently it can only be done like this

```
GET /msdo/v1/Player?id=1
```

I've been trying to change quite a few things.

the code as it is right now is pretty standard:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "{id}")]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

I've tried with changeing {id} into {*id}
I've tried with changeing {id} into /{id}
I've tried a few other things where I started to change default route however that made it even worse by making a 500 error.
so here I am looking for an answer to something that seemed so simple before I started and have been quite a hurdle to get over.

**EDIT 1:**
added more code from my controller

```
[Route("/msdo/v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PlayerController : ControllerBase
{

    // GET /msdo/v1/player/5

    [HttpGet(Name = "{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
 }
```

**Edit 2:** Found a Possible solution. I don't know if it is a good one so I'm going to leave this question open to see if someone comes up with a better solution.

However here is my solution to the question:

```
 [HttpGet("/msdo/v1/[controller]/{id}", Name = "{id}")]
 public string Get(int id)
 {
      return "value";
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this adding route attribute `[Route("{id}")]` above your method.
And insted of [HttpGet(Name = "{id}")] just leave [HttpGet].

Comment: well if I do that it does not work and I get a internal server error with swagger

Comment: can you share your controller code ?

Comment: I've added it to the question under Edit

Comment: updated the answer, removed / in front of the id. Can you try again ?

Comment: result is the same as before. However I think I found a way to get it to do what I want I'm going to add it to the question and then if someone finds a better way to do it I just hope they will post an answer with it here. 
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: not sure how you are getting error again. i just teded it it works

Comment: well not sure what changed after I got my solution to work I tried yours again and now it works also. not sure which is better but I will mark yours as the solution next weekend if nobody else writes a definitive better solution before then.